# How to slice an array value to get only the last 2 numbers in that array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array,

```
arr = [{number1: 1523, number2: 43677, number3: 643}]
```

How to slice this array to get only the last 2 numbers. I hope receive result like this:

```
arr = [{number1: 23, number2: 77, number3: 43}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: There are a few different ways this could be done. What have you tried? Can you update the code to include anything you have tried and any errors you got?

Comment: That's an object, not an array. It just happens to be inside an array.

Comment: And you're getting the last 2 digits of a number, not characters.

Comment: Hint: modulus operator.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a newbie and try to learn Javascript. I don't have any idea for this problem. Please help  me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mutate the first object inside the array it would be something like this :

```js
let arr = [{
  number1: 1523,
  number2: 43677,
  number3: 643
}];

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arr[0])) {
  arr[0][key] = value % 100;
}

console.log(arr);
```